# Luigi read application specific property file and make it available across all tasks

Tags: luigi

I am using the luigi for machine learning workflow, I have requirement like there will be a config or property file for environment specific.

can someone tell me how to load the environment specific property file and make it available across the all tasks.

Answer (score 0):

We have no idea how to load your specific property file. But, assuming you can load it, simply include a field in your config file for luigi on the path to the file and then load it in each of your tasks that requires it.